# Capturing depth using the lidar camera sample code: Caused GPU Timeout Error (00000002:kIOGPUCommandBufferCallbackErrorTimeout)

Tags: swift, iphone, crash, lidar

I am hoping someone here may be able to help me with an issue I have got.

After downloading [the project code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/additional_data_capture/capturing_depth_using_the_lidar_camera) and running the Swift sample code on an iPhone 14 Pro, the app crashes intermittently, throwing this error:

> Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Caused GPU Timeout Error (00000002:kIOGPUCommandBufferCallbackErrorTimeout)

Sometimes it will crash within a few seconds, sometimes it can take around 10 minutes, sometimes even longer.

Has anyone here experienced this crash from the sample code, or using the LiDAR camera?

I have spent a long time trying to solve this issue, I have searched the web high and low and submitted (I think) a report to Apple about it. I am unable to get xcode to show me the line of code where the crash is happening.

I say "I think" as the only place I could find to contact Apple was through the Feedback Assistant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

After numerous hours (or days), I have finally found where the error is being thrown.

In the MetalTextureViewColor.swift file, there is a draw method. The error is being thrown at this line

encoder.endEncoding*(

with the following error

> MTLCommandBuffer execution failed. The commands associated with an encoder caused an error

Here is the whole draw function

```
override func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        guard parent.capturedData.colorY != nil && parent.capturedData.colorCbCr != nil else {
            print("There's no content to display.")
            return
        }
        guard let commandBuffer = metalCommandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else { return }
        guard let passDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor else { return }
        guard let encoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: passDescriptor) else { return }
        // Vertex and Texture coordinates data (x,y,u,v) * 4 ordered for triangle strip.
        let vertexData: [Float] = [-1, -1, 1, 1,
                                    1, -1, 1, 0,
                                   -1,  1, 0, 1,
                                    1,  1, 0, 0]
        encoder.setVertexBytes(vertexData, length: vertexData.count * MemoryLayout<Float>.stride, index: 0)
        encoder.setFragmentTexture(parent.capturedData.colorY!, index: 0)
        encoder.setFragmentTexture(parent.capturedData.colorCbCr!, index: 1)
        encoder.setDepthStencilState(depthState)
        encoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
        encoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangleStrip, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 4)
        
        // error happening on the line below
        encoder.endEncoding()


        commandBuffer.present(view.currentDrawable!)
        commandBuffer.commit()
        //commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
    }
```

Is there any way I can catch this error, and ignore it, and continue the app running?

Comment: have you ever found out the solution? Also, curious how did you find out it was that line that caused the problem since I also couldn't get XCode to pinpoint the line number that causes that error.

Comment: Hi Zeo2396, have you experienced the issue too? I did hear back from Apple but they wanted me to make all sorts of videos about it showing it crashing etc, but I didn't have time, also they could just run their code on their own devices and see the crash for themselves (which would have been a lot quicker and more helpful). I found the line through lots of exception catching and it was caught on the line shown in my UPDATE. The best I have done to handle the crash (which makes the app freeze) is when the exception is caught I fire an event that restarts the LiDAR capture, not ideal but works

Comment: Yes, i also noticed this happens on all devices that I had developed in (iPhone 13 Pro, iPad Pro, iPhone 15 Pro max). Do you happen to have the link to the Apple's post? I can also comment so that they know this is an issue experienced by multiple people. If you happen to have the line (debug print, or Metal debugger) tool that you used, I can try to dig deeper too. The shaders used by this pipeline are so simple so I don't understand how that caused the GPU to timeout!). How did you work around? 
```
    do {
        try encoder.endEncoding()
    } catch {
        //start cam
    }
```